# Python Head vs. Tail Recursion - No StackOverflow Error for Head and seems to perfom better?

Tags: python, recursion

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(15000)

import time

def factorialHead(n):
    if n <= 1: 
        return 1
    else: 
        return n * factorialHead(n - 1)

print("Head Recursion:")
now = time.time()
factorialHead(10000) # this should break as I understand - stackoverflow (seems to work fine??)
print(time.time() - now)

def factorialTail(n, currentValue = 1):
    if n <= 1: 
        return currentValue
    else:
        return factorialTail(n-1, n*currentValue)

print("Tail Recursion:")
now = time.time()
factorialTail(10000)
print(time.time() - now)

# Output:
# Head Recursion:
# 0.02311873435974121
# Tail Recursion:
# 0.05035591125488281

#Switched Order
# Tail Recursion:
# 0.05422401428222656
# Head Recursion:
# 0.017311573028564453
```

Somewhat new to python and coding in general. Was playing around with some head and tail recursive functions and noticed some strange behaviour in a head recursive function. This is a sort of "recreation" of what I encountered. As I understand the stack, the head recursion above should throw a stackoverflow error. Not only does it not do this, but it seems to perform better than the tail recursive equivalent.
Can someone please explain what is going on here, what am I missing?

Python=3.8.10 (just for reference)

Comment: well for starters, you should know that in Python, there is no tail-call optimization, so *both* should cause a recursion error at the same depth.

Comment: Anyway, you set the maximum recursion limit to `15000`, why do you *expect* it to break at `10000`??? Note, both break if you use `headRec(15000)` and `tailRec(15000)` raise the expected error

Comment: First of all, a single experiment is insufficient.  Second, you should use `timeit`, rather than a one-off `time.time` reference, to reduce noise in your observations.  Third, since Python generally doesn't optimize tail calls, you're trying to measure something that isn't in your run-time system.  Next, as Juan said first, you haven't hit the stack limit you specified, so it's not at all clear why you expect your program to throw and exception.

Comment: For an illustration of how to implement proper tail recursion in Python, see [this blog](https://chrispenner.ca/posts/python-tail-recursion).

Comment: Finally, since both functions recur to the same depth, why do you think exactly one of them should fault?  Are you looking for the recursion to be reduced to a loop?

Comment: "what am I missing?" It might help if you were to explain what you *think* is going on, and *why*. How do you "understand the stack" and why do you think "head recursion above should throw a stackoverflow error"? As you have discovered yourself, the only expectation you have cited (head recursion should throw an error) is wrong.